# How to return view with @RestController in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

Return view page with `@RestController` in spring and use as rest service.

Comment: A Rest controller should more likely be returning JSON, or plain text. Then what called the controller should be making the view of it.

Comment: highlight the code section

Answer (score 1):

`@RestController` is a convenience annotation that combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. `@ResponseBody` on the other hand indicates that a method return value should be bound to the response body.

So either you have a `@RestController` and return objects or you could create `@Controller` and just have some of the methods annotated as `@ResponseBody` and some returning views.

Have a look at these resources:

- [Rest Controller Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)
- [Response body Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)
- [Article with deeper explanation](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-framework-restcontroller-vs-controller)